# Unable to connect to internet in debian squeeze

Tags: networking, debian-squeeze

I  recently installed Debian squeeze on my  development machine every things went well i was able to connect to the Internet yesterday i moved my hard disk to another machine ,i can't able to connect to the Internet in Debian,but i can connect to it using Windows XP.

i tried the following commands but no use not working

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
/var/log/syslog        doesn't show any error
ping www.google.com    results no host found
```

**More details**

**ifconfig**

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:13737 (13.4 KiB)  TX bytes:13737 (13.4 KiB)
```

**netstat -rn**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
```

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

```
domain Home
search Home
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**ifconfig -a**

```
eth1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:f0:49:f6:45:ae  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:26 Base address:0x6000 

lo    Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
      RX packets:70 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:70 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:18029 (17.6 KiB)  TX bytes:18029 (17.6 KiB)
```

Comment: Can you post the output from netstat -rn, ifconfig, cat /etc/resolv.conf, anonymise any IP addresses if you wish, but please ensure they are consistent.

Comment: the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces` would also be useful

Comment: i added few details plz check it

Comment: Do any devices in LAN respond to ping, and if yes, does 8.8.8.8 respond to ping?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` is configured for`eth0` however, you don't have an `eth0` but an `eth1`.

udev tries to statically name the ethernet cards, by assigning a semi-permanent name to cards the first time they are seen.  You can get rid of the 'reservation' of eth0 from your previous ethernet card by deleting the line from `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` which ends with `name=eth0` and the line which ends with `name=eth1`.  Then upon the next reboot (or when you run `udevadm trigger`), your ethernet card will be assigned eth0 semi-permanently.

You can also change eth1 to eth0 temporarily by running `ip link set name eth0 dev eth1`, after which `/etc/init.d/networking stop ; /etc/init.d/networking start` should get you back on the network.

Comment: great stew it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Your description is not enough. You need to provide us with more information to help you better.

As a guess, I can say that your primary network interface has changed after moving the HD drive to another machine. So, you need to check the interface name using `ifconfig -a`. Then, you can edit the network interfaces configuration file `/etc/network/interfaces` to match the new name. When done, you can do `/etc/init.d/networking restart`.

Comment: i tried but not working